# Como usar um ng-class na tag <html>

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Estou utilizando o framework AngularJS e preciso que a minha tag  ela receba um class dinamica exemplo:

```
<html lang="en" id="ng-app" ng-app="app" ng-class="app.title">
</html>
```

Esse app.title receberá um valor do mongo.

Alguém sabe me dizer se isso é possivél? E se dessa forma é possivél retornar o nome da class sabendo que tenho uma string nesse campo?

Comment: Acho que ninguém sabe essa resposta. O atributo `ng-class` funciona em elementos normais, mas no HTML eu não sei. Provavelmente você terá que definir os atributos `ng-app`, `ng-controller` e só então `ng-class` talvez funcione, todos na tag `html`. Teste. É o jeito mais fácil de descobrir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traduzindo da documentação do Angularjs(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

A diretiva ngClass permite que você altere dinamicamente o CSS de um elemento HTML fazendo um 'databinding' de uma expressão que representa todas as classes a serem adicionadas.
A diretiva opera de três maneiras diferentes, dependendo de qual dos três tipos a seguir a expressão for avaliada:

1. Se a expressão for uma string, a string deve conter varias classes separadas por espaços;
2. Se a expressão for um array, cada elemento do array deve ser uma string com uma ou mais classes separadas por espaços;
3. Se a expressão for um objeto, então para cada item chave-valor do objeto a chave correspondente será usada como nome da classe.

Veja este plunker como exemplo: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview